# Can a lambda be passed a as a template parameter in C++17?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

I've read multiple answers on SO with lambdas being passed to class templates but for some reason I cant achieve it... I am using g++ version 9 with C++17 being used.

```
#include <string>

struct Type {
    Type();
    Type(int);
    int theVal();
};

template<typename Key, typename Value, Key(*KeyFunc)(Type t) = nullptr>
struct MyClass {
    MyClass(){}

    ~MyClass(){}

    void add(const Key key, const Value value){
         //do stuff
    }

    void add(const Value value){
         this->add(KeyFunc(value), value);
    }
};

int main(){
    MyClass<
      int,
      std::string,
      +[](Type t){
        return t.theVal();
      }
    > instance;

    Type value(100);

    instance.add(value);

    return 0;
}
```

The error message tells me I cant have a lambda in a template.

Comment: What is Type in the instance?

Comment: its just a sample place holder for the sake of the example

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it need to first declared outside the template parameter, and the lambda must be captureless:

```
auto lambda = [](Type t) {
    return t.theVal();
};

// Works, C++17 allows constexpr conversion for nttp
MyClass<int, Type, lambda> instance;
```

In C++20, you can use C++17's `auto` template parameter and a lambda directly in the template parameters:

```
constexpr auto noop = [](auto&& v) -> decltype(auto) {
    return static_cast<decltype(v)&&>(v);
};

template<typename Key, typename Value, auto KeyFunc = noop>
class MyClass {
    // ...
};

MyClass<
    int,
    Type,
    [](Type t) {
        return t.theVal();
    }
> instance;
```

[C++20 Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7d442u)

[C++17 Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/nfgdo6)

Comment: Thanks, what about "+[](Type t){"? Is the "+" a real thing for c++17

Comment: + exist to force the lambda to decay into a function pointer. It doesn't work with visual studio though

Comment: Your gives "error: could not convert template argument '& lambda' from 'main()::<lambda(Type)>*' to 'int (*)(Type)'
     > instance;"

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno for a lambda to be convertible to a function pointer, it must have no captures. Try with my live example.